# vba preguntar cuanto tiempo esperar a que cargue la pagina

Tags: excel, vba

Buen día comunidad, mi pregunta es quiza un poco rara, pero tengo un codigo que hace scraping a una pagina, esta pagina a veces carga lento y necesito saber como puedo desde un inputbox preguntar al usuario cuantos segundos quiero esperar a que cargue la pagina antes de hacer la siguiente consulta, actualmente lo tengo en 4 segundos, pero hay dias que son hasta 7 o 10 segundos por consulta, lo que quiero lograr es que me pregunte al inicio cuanto quiero esperar

```
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mete el total de segundos en una variable y listo:

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim Tiempo As Long
Tiempo = InputBox("¿Cuántos segundos?", "TIEMPO", 4)

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(Format(Tiempo / 60 / 60 / 24, "hh:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: SUPER ya quedó master Esei, gracias !!

Comment: `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Tiempo)`